# Does anyone know this math font?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, math-fonts

new to this forum. Does anyone know what math font this is and how I can use it/if it's available free? It's from "An Introduction to the Theory of Mechanism Design" by Tilman Börgers (this clip from page 12). Thanks very much.

[image: Page 12, Börgers, An Introduction to the Theory of Mechanism Design]

Comment: Is it `\usepackage{newtxmath}`??

Comment: Do you have the pdf file? Then you can check it for the used fonts ...

Comment: Unfortunately it's not newtxmath and I don't have a pdf (I managed to find this image elsewhere on the internet, not a pdf)

Comment: This font is called: `ArnoPro` + OUP1 .ttf: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~tborgers/Sample.pdf

Comment: The font OUP1 is a proprietary font of Oxford University Press. I don't think they allow using it outside their book production.

Comment: @Sebastiano Feel free to write an answer, you found the pdf ;-)

Comment: @Mensch no no, I'm scarce user :-):-); you're welcome.

Comment: thanks everyone!

Comment: To me it seems like the latin letters in math come from ArnoPro, while the greek delta and theta do not.

Comment: @mickep I agree with you. The fonts are also CMSY, MSAM, MTEX, MTSYN, OUP2, RMTMI, DSROM.